# std::fs::File + documentation + try! = E0308

Tags: rust

I want to create an empty file, so I took [an example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html) and I used today's nightly build

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let mut f = try!(File::create("foo"));
}
```

Running `rustc` has the errors:

```
<std macros>:5:8: 6:42 error: mismatched types:
 expected `()`,
    found `core::result::Result<_, _>`
(expected (),
    found enum `core::result::Result`) [E0308]
<std macros>:5 return $ crate:: result:: Result:: Err (
<std macros>:6 $ crate:: convert:: From:: from ( err ) ) } } )
<std macros>:1:1: 6:48 note: in expansion of try!
file_io.rs:5:17: 5:42 note: expansion site
<std macros>:5:8: 6:42 help: pass `--explain E0308` to see a detailed explanation
error: aborting due to previous error
```

If I remove `try!`, it compiles, but how I should handle errors? And why is the example not compiled as is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`try!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.try!.html) is a macro that is to be used in functions that return a `Result`. Therefore, it cannot be used in the `main` function, because it returns unit (the empty tuple).

Look at how it expands:

```
fn main() {
    let mut f = match File::create("foo") {
        Ok(val) => val,
        Err(err) => return Err(From::from(err)),
    };
}
```

http://blog.burntsushi.net/rust-error-handling/ is a good article about error handling in Rust; for simple scripts like yours probably is, using `Result::unwrap` (`File::create("foo").unwrap()`) is probably reasonable.

Answer (score 3):

Let's have a look at the `try!()` macro:

```
macro_rules! try {
    ($expr:expr) => (match $expr {
        $crate::result::Result::Ok(val) => val,
        $crate::result::Result::Err(err) => {
            return $crate::result::Result::Err($crate::convert::From::from(err))
        }
    })
}
```

As you can see, either `try!()` yields `val`  as an expression, either it returns an `Err` out of the function. So after the macro is processed, the unwrapped code looks like:

```
fn main() {
    let mut f = (match File::create("foo") {
        Ok(val) => val,
        Err(err) => {
            return Err(...)
        }
    })
}
```

Hopefully the error is obvious now: `main()` should return `()`, but you return an `Err` (which is of type `Result<File>`).

The moral of the story is that you use `try!()` in the wrong scenario here. It should only be used inside a function which is already designed to return a `Result`, just like you would rethrow (bubble up) an exception in C++ or Java. In your case though, you need to explicitly deal with the error -- there's no bubbling up possible. A possible solution, though not very elegant, is to use `.unwrap()` to crash the program in case of an `Err`.